# Datepicker can't be saved to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, yii, datepicker

I'm working on a program with a datepicker, but when i try to submit it to the MySQL database it gives the following error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0000-00-00' for key 'Dag'.
```

The code that i use for the datepicker is:

```
<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Dag'); ?>
    <?php

    $form->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'Dag',
        'htmlOptions' => array(
        'size' => '10',         // textField size
        'maxlength' => '10',    // textField maxlength

        ),
    ));
    ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'Dag'); ?>
</div>
```

I know it says there already is a date named 0000-00-00 but i didn't add that one, but date 2014-09-02!

Comment: After you calmly read the error message, what do you conclude?

Comment: That there already is date named 0000-00-00. But the string that i wanted to enter was 2014-09-02.

Comment: Ok, so you sent `2014-09-02` (or you *think* you sent it), and MySQL wants to insert `0000-00-00`. Obviously, you didn't tell it to insert `0000-00-00` so you try to find out why it thinks that. Where do you start?

Comment: I really have no clue... :(

Comment: Start from the part where I said you *think* you sent it - inspect what your browser really sends and what PHP actually receives.

Comment: @MvanOeffel: Follow the value from where you enter it to where it goes to the database statement.  Somewhere along the way the value is being lost.  Where?  When you monitor your web request in your browser's debugging tools, is the value there?  When you capture it server-side, is it still correct?  How do you send it to the database?

Comment: try to inspect your $model->attributes by  
    print_r($model->Dag) preior to save in database

Answer (score 0):

If the attribute `Dag` is considered `unsafe` by your Yii `ActiveRecord` model, then the new value sent from DatePicker (and assigned possibly by `$model->attributes = $_POST['ModelName'];`) won't get assigned unless you assign it manually like so: `$model->Dag = $_POST['ModelName']['Dag']`

If you want, you could also set the `Dag` attribute as safe in your model:

`public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            ...,
            array('Dag', 'safe'),
        );
    }`